# NLog console highlight properties

Tags: c#, nlog

I've watched the following [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_iryZxv8Rxw) explaining about Serilog. I would like to use structured logging in my application as well (at least parts of it), but I prefer to use NLog (1) because it's already part of our stack and we're used to it and prefer to have the same logger on across our projects, and (2) I have read the comparison [here](https://medium.com/dev-genius/serilog-vs-nlog-7d0a322a4732) and seems like NLog is more performant.

So I read that NLog also [support structured logging](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging) and I have implemented it in a test application without a problem. It works very well.

What I saw in the video and liked about Serilog, is when writing to console it highlights the parameters passed to the logging function like this:

[image: Example of Serilog console parsing]

I would like to have the same on the console application I'm currently building. I have tried both `Console` target and `ColoredConsole` but non has that effect. Is it possible in NLog?

This is my targets configurations:

```
<target name="file"
            xsi:type="File"
            archiveEvery="Day"
            archiveFileName="Logs\log.{#}.txt"
            fileName="Logs\log.txt"
            archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"
            archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
            archiveAboveSize="104857600"
            maxArchiveFiles="30"
            layout="${longdate} | ${uppercase:${level}} | ${logger} | ${threadid} | ${message} ${exception}"
            />

    <target xsi:type="ColoredConsole"
          name="ColorConsole"
          layout="${uppercase:${level}}: ${message} ${exception:innerFormat=Message,StackTrace}"
          header="Memoriez API"
          useDefaultRowHighlightingRules="false"
          >
      <highlight-word foregroundColor="Green" ignoreCase="true" text="info" wholeWords="true" />
      <highlight-word foregroundColor="Red" ignoreCase="true" text="warn" wholeWords="true" />
      <highlight-word backgroundColor="Red" foregroundColor="White" ignoreCase="true" text="error" wholeWords="true" />
      <highlight-row backgroundColor="DarkRed" foregroundColor="Yellow" condition="level == LogLevel.Fatal" />
    </target>
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you can colorized the parameters in `ColoredConsoleTarget`. It might be possible to use WordHighlighting, but you would quickly run into issues where matching a number would highlight all numbers and not just the parameter.

My guess is that you would need to write a custom `ColoredConsoleTarget` in order to highlight parameters. I just looked at the `src\NLog\Targets\ColoredConsoleTarget.cs` file and it only offers `RowHighlightingRules` and `WordHighlightingRules`. It looks like when the color codes are applied the `LogEventInfo` has been rendered into a plain string.

I think you would need to write a custom `RenderLogEvent` function that would render the color escape sequences for parameters. It would be a bit tricky because the `GenerateColorEscapeSequences` for WordHighlighting would escape any color sequences generated before it is called).

Here are my thoughts:

1. Create a new class `ColoredParamConsoleTarget` with code copied from    `ColoredConsoleTarget`. It doesn't look like there are virtual methods to just override the existing class.
2. Create a `ColoredRenderLogEvent` method and parse for parameters and add color sequences before and after parameters.
3. Replace calls to `RenderLogEvent` with `ColoredRenderLogEvent`

Comment: Alternative add a new option to `ColoredConsoleTarget` called `IncludeEventProperties` that appends the LogEventInfo.Properties as footer to output with coloring. PullRequests are welcome to the NLog project: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/